# Let $P\geq0$, $P\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. For every $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ there exists $c\geq0$: $A^\top P+PA\leq cP$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-norms, lyapunov-functions

I want to prove/disprove the following claim.

*Claim.* Let $P\geq0$, $P\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. For every $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ there exists $c\geq0$: $$A^\top P+PA\leq cP.$$

*Draft of the proof.* Let $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Either $x\in\mathrm{Ker}\hspace{.5mm} P$, i.e., $x^\top Px=0$, or $x\notin\mathrm{Ker}\hspace{.5mm}P$, i.e., $x^\top Px>0$. If $x\in\mathrm{Ker}\hspace{.5mm}P$, then $c=0$ satisfies the above. If $x\notin\mathrm{Ker}\hspace{.5mm}P$, then the above is equivalent to
$$\frac{x^\top(A^\top P+PA)x}{x^\top Px}\leq c\dots$$

Then, I guess that from here I need to play with estimates, but I do not know how exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is not true. Take $ P = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Then,
\begin{align} 
A^T P + P A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}. 
\end{align}
For $c \geq 0$,
\begin{align}
c P - (A^T P + P A) = \begin{pmatrix} c & -1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
The eigenvalues of this matrix are $\frac{c \pm \sqrt{c^2 + 4}}{2}$. Hence, there is always a negative eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1):

This is false. E.g.
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&1},\quad P=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}
\implies cP-(A^\top P+PA)=\pmatrix{c-2&-1\\ -1&0}
$$
but the latter is indefinite for every real number $c$.