# Let $P>0$, $P\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. For every $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ there exists $c>0$: $A^\top P+PA\leq cP$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-norms

I want to prove/disprove the following claim:

Let $P>0$, $P\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. For every $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ there exists $c>0$: $A^\top P+PA\leq cP$.

This is a follow up to [Let $P\geq0$, $P\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. For every $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ there exists $c\geq0$: $A^\top P+PA\leq cP$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4801665/let-p-geq0-p-in-mathbbrn-times-n-for-every-a-in-mathbbrn-times-n/4801856#4801856)

Comment: How do the answers to your previous question not answer this one?

Comment: The previous claim is not true. However, by including stronger assumptions on P (P positive definite and not semidefinite), the claim may be true.

Comment: Yes, you might be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true. You may simply pick any positive number $c\ge\rho\left(P^{-1/2}A^TP^{1/2}+P^{1/2}AP^{-1/2}\right)$, so that $cI\succeq P^{-1/2}A^TP^{1/2}+P^{1/2}AP^{-1/2}$ and in turn
$$
cP
\succeq P^{1/2}\left(P^{-1/2}A^TP^{1/2}+P^{1/2}AP^{-1/2}\right)P^{1/2}
=A^TP+PA.
$$

Comment: Are both $P^{1/2}$ and $P^{-1/2}$ well-defined in this case? how are you guaranteed that $c>0$? I see, you can take any positive number greater than $\rho$. Btw, what is $\rho$ in your writing?

Comment: All eigevalues are positiv, so $P^{1/2}, P^{-1/2}$ are well-defined (you can use the spectral theorem). The $\rho$ is the spectral radius and such a constant exists, because all operators in this post are bounded.